# Object invisible in shading

Tags: shaders

[image]

Hello i need help my object is invisble in shading which makes it little hard to work with please can some  help me with this problem?

Comment: I wonder if it's not a problem of graphic card driver?

Comment: Hmm could be i try using some different versions

Comment: No sadly the problem remains :(

Comment: it happens with any object you create? any version of Blender? maybe give the specifications of your computer and drivers, maybe someone will know...

Comment: It happened on all objects but i solved it i was trying to solve this for soo long and only thing that i needed to do was to enable the ,,high quality normals"  in render properties but still thanks for your help iam happy that someone reacted on my problem that quickly

Comment: maybe give a full answer so that if anyone meet the same problem he will be able to solve it

Comment: Thats a good idea :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i solved the problem only thing you need to do is to enable the ,,High Quality Normals"
[image]