# Most things not rendering correctly

Tags: eevee-render-engine, workbench-render-engine

## Description:

This occurs in pretty much every part of Blender, but here is an example in geometry nodes
Solid view:
[image: some objects not rendered]

Workbench:
[image: objects scattered about incorrectly]

Eevee:
[image: same as in workbench]

Cycles (how it's supposed to look):
[image: how it's supposed to look]

note: I'm just making this to share this knowledge, as it took me months to find this answer and I don't want anyone to have to go through that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the Performance tab in Eevee's settings, check High Quality Normals
It's a really simple solution, but it worked for me

[image: image of render properties tab with the performance subtab(?) open and High Quality Normals checked]

Comment: Known problem probably due to graphics card drivers. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/204225/object-invisible-in-shading/204227#204227 among many other reports.